# changing the priority of network interface

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, ppp

I want my ppp0 connection to have higher priority over wlan0. I added following lines to `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

```
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    up ifmetric wlan0 20
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#route table after modifying
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.43.1    0.0.0.0         UG    20     0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     20     0        0 wlan0
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     20     0        0 wlan0
220.224.141.145 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
```

As you can see, metric of wlan0 changed to 20, but still it is preferred over ppp0 as default gateway. When i checked man page of route, it was mentioned "metric was not used by recent kernels".

I can change the route manually by deleting the unwanted gw and adding ppp0 as gw. But when wlan0 disconnects and reconnects, the routing table changed to default. How could i set my ppp0 as default gw permanently?

Comment: adding `ppp0`as `gw` with command `route add default dev ppp0` or on some different way?

Comment: but it will change if wlan0 reconnects, or when you boot the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several possibility to change the default route.

Nice place for this kind of action is in `/etc/network/if-down.d/` or `/etc/network/if-up.d/`

You can in this folder put some script and make action. For example put
this script in `/etc/ppp/if-up.d/` to make default route to `ppp0` interface every time when go up, make script called `script` with execute permissions 755

`sudo nano /etc/ppp/if-up.d/script`

```
# Check for specific interface if desired
[ "$IFACE" != "ppp0" ] || exit 0
# Do something
sudo route add default dev ppp0
```

`chmod 755 /etc/ppp/if-up.d/script`

In second case `wifi` reconnect, make one more script aka script2

`sudo nano /etc/network/if-up.d/script2`

```
# Check for specific interface if desired
[ "$IFACE" != "wlan0" ] || exit 0
# Do something
sudo route add default dev ppp0
```

This will if `wlan0` go up set default route to `ppp0`, if is `ppp0` down route will not be changed from `wlan0`.

Try.

Edit 1

Based on internet research, for `ppp0` interface you move script in `/etc/ppp/if-up.d`

Comment: what does [ "$IFACE" != "ppp0" ] || exit 0 this line represent?

Comment: compare `ifup` and `ifdown` action against interface. If is script in `if-up.d`, check `ifup` action that belongs `ppp0` interface and go to command.

Comment: Scripts in if-up.d are not executing when ppp0 is up. I tried with sample shell with only this command "sudo touch /home/user/test.txt". No file is created for ppp0 (the script is not executing). But for wlan it is working

Comment: I am using wvdial to start the pppd.

Comment: Pelase, give me output from command `ifconfig` when `wvdial` is connected.

Comment: ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
inet addr:115.241.58.163  P-t-P:220.224.141.145  Mask:255.255.255.255
UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:106 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:108 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
 RX bytes:26594 (26.5 KB)  TX bytes:19725 (19.7 KB)

Comment: Name on the interface is `ppp0` script should be work. Script will be executed only when interface change state, in this case, from down to up.

Comment: Couldn't get you. Interface changes stated from down to up, when we disconnect and connect again. I am doing that, but still the script is not executing.

Comment: Are you set permision? `chmod 755 /etc/network/if-up.d/script`

Comment: yes. The output of ls -l. -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   45 May 22 16:21 test. By the way, script name is test

Comment: I asked a question on this. http://askubuntu.com/questions/626953/scripts-in-if-up-d-not-executed-when-ppp-connection-is-created

Comment: If you have usb modem try to change `ppp0` with `usb0`