# scripts in if-up.d not executed when ppp connection is created

Tags: networking, scripts, ifconfig, ppp

I have a simple script "test" in `/etc/network/if-up.d` directory. The script contains below commands. It creates a empty text file, whenever an interfaces changes state from down to up.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo touch /home/duser/test1.txt
```

But the script is not executing when ppp connection is established. The ppp connection belongs to an usb-modem. The pppd daemon will be initiated by wvdial. I tried disconnecting and connecting my wlan, then the script is executing. But it doesn't work for ppp. Note: The script have 755 permission

Comment: Use `/etc/ppp/ip-up.d` instead, if the script is specifically for `ppp`.

Comment: sometimes it needs to have a prefix like '0000script' otherwise it does not works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example put this script in `/etc/ppp/ip-up.d/` to make default route to `ppp0` interface every time when go up, make script called script with execute `permissions 755`

`sudo nano /etc/ppp/ip-up.d/script`

```
# Check for specific interface if desired
[ "$PPP_IFACE" != "ppp0" ] || exit 0
# Do something
sudo route add default dev ppp0
chmod 755 /etc/ppp/if-up.d/script
```

Try

Comment: I did the edit :)

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no need for sudo inside script